# NameError: Factory name not defined - Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am getting error

> NameError: name 'Factory' is not defined

when I try to import Factory in kv file. But I have already imported in py file.

Below is my code,

Kv file:

```
<MessagePopup>:
    id: popup
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "User Verification"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 300,300
    space_x: self.size[0]/6
    space_y: self.size[1]/6
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: 20
        padding: popup.space_x, popup.space_y
        Label:
            text: "Click to verify"
        Button:
            id:popup_phone
            text:"Verify"
            size_hint_y: 5.5
            on_release:
                Factory.PhonePopup().open()
```

```
<PhonePopup@Popup>:
    id: "Phno_popup"
    title: "Verify"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 300,300
    space_x: self.size[0]/6
    space_y: self.size[1]/6
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: 20
        padding: Phno_popup.space_x, Phno_popup.space_y
        Label:
            text:"Enter"
            size_hint_y: 5.5
        TextInput:
            id: id_phno
            size_hint_y: 5.5
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: "Verify"
            size_hint_y: 5.5
            on_press: root.id_verify()
```

Py file:

```py
import mysql.connector
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.factory import Factory
```

I am beginner in kivy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import Factory in kv too.
Add the following line to the top of your `.kv` file:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
```

Comment: dont remove the #